# Modulur arithmetic logic to reduce calculations

Tags: java, modular-arithmetic

the concept of mod to retain only the remainder instead of the big number.

formula to compute:

=> Summation i=1 to i=N { i%m }

Constraint

1 ≤ N ≤ 10^9
1 ≤ m ≤ 10^9

How can modulus used so that we need not to sum up to 10^9 (big Number).
Java code gives terminated due to timeout or CPU code duped Error on big number execution.

CODE: k is the summation result to be printed.

```
for (BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
                bi.compareTo(N) <= 0;
                bi = bi.add(BigInteger.ONE)){

               k = k.add(bi.mod(m));

             }  
        System.out.println(k);
```

Comment: Don't use `BigInteger`. The 10^9 limit is there for a reason: it means that both `N` and `m` can be safely stored in a 32-bit integer or `int`. Your final result should fit comfortably in a `long`.

Comment: thanks for the comment T.C.: i need  help with learning concept of modular arithmetic to deal with big integer operation. Any reference will be appreciated. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're asking in which case it's really more of an arithmetic than a programming question but here it is anyway. 
Try a concrete example. If you have the sum with i from 1 to 10 of i % 3, what you are adding its 1 + 2 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 0 + 1. You can see that you have the same thing over and over so what you need to do is figure out what that is,  figure out how many times you need to add it, then add on the leftover bit on the end.

Comment: thanks for posting, implemented same, did not help - any other option respect to modulus

Comment: Is it giving you the wrong answer or is it still not finishing?